# Разная верстка для десктопа и мобильных устройств

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Привет. В фронт-энде слабо разбираюсь, поэтому нид хелп) Нужно условную карточку товара по разному сверстать для десктопа и для мобильных устройств. Например для десктопа все элементы расположить вертикально, а для мобильной версии картинку расположить слева, а все остальные элементы справа по вертикали. Буду рад любым советам.

Пример кода:

```html
<div class="product">
  <h4 class="name">Orange</h4>
  <img class="image" src="orange.jpg">
  <p class="price">40$</p>
  <form action="https://ru.stackoverflow.com">
      <input type="submit" value="Buy!" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью медиа запросов:

```
@media screen and (max-width: (размер экрана)px) {
    стили каждого элемента , как он будет выглядеть если размер экрана меньше n-го значения
}
```

Comment: благодарю, то что надо!